# How do I find and compare dates in file?

Tags: python, date, datetime

I don't really know how exactly to explain this so please view the examples given
I have a lot of lines but I'll just show 5.

```
A1234567, Amen, Mr, 18/01/1999, Construction, Head, 987654321, FullTime, 5000
A2345678, Bmen, Mr, 23/04/1994, Office, Worker, 987654321, FullTime, 3000
A3456789, Cwomen, Mrs, 13/01/1996, Aviation, Pilot, 987654321, FullTime, 4000
A4567890, Dmen, Mr, 18/01/2002, Construction, Assistant Head, 987654321, FullTime, 4500
A5678901, Ewomen, Ms, 18/01/1991, Construction, Worker, 987654321, FullTime, 2500
```

I want to get people that is AFTER year 1995 and deduct their salary (last value) by 10%
so far i can do till

```
with open('list.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        split = line.split(",")
        
        if split[3] < 1/1/1995:
```

the if statement is wrong, The result should be like this with everyone AFTER year 1995 with 10% deduction, those who are BEFORE 1995 are not touched

```
A1234567, Amen, Mr, 18/01/1999, Construction, Head, 987654321, FullTime, 4500
A2345678, Bmen, Mr, 23/04/1994, Office, Worker, 987654321, FullTime, 3000
A3456789, Cwomen, Mrs, 13/01/1996, Aviation, Pilot, 987654321, FullTime, 3600
A4567890, Dmen, Mr, 18/01/2002, Construction, Assistant Head, 987654321, FullTime, 4050
A5678901, Ewomen, Ms, 18/01/1991, Construction, Worker, 987654321, FullTime, 2500
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Chris suggested this is a good task for the [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/) library, you could do something like (I've added column names for clarity):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(
    'data.csv', sep=', ',
    names=['id', 'name', 'prefix', 'date', 'work', 'position', 'number', 'work_type', 'salary']
)


def parse_date(col):
    return pd.to_datetime(col, infer_datetime_format=True)


df['salary'] = df.apply(
    lambda col: int(col['salary'] * 0.9) if (parse_date(col['date']) > datetime.datetime(1995, 1, 1)) else col[
        'salary'],
    axis=1
)

print(df.to_csv(header=False, index=False, sep=','))
```

**Output:**

```
A1234567,Amen,Mr,18/01/1999,Construction,Head,987654321,FullTime,4500
A2345678,Bmen,Mr,23/04/1994,Office,Worker,987654321,FullTime,3000
A3456789,Cwomen,Mrs,13/01/1996,Aviation,Pilot,987654321,FullTime,3600
A4567890,Dmen,Mr,18/01/2002,Construction,Assistant Head,987654321,FullTime,4050
A5678901,Ewomen,Ms,18/01/1991,Construction,Worker,987654321,FullTime,2500
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [datetimes.strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)

```
from datetime import datetime

with open('list.txt') as file:
    threshold = datetime(1995, 1, 1)

    for line in file:
        lines = line.split(",")
        
        salary = l[-1]
        date = datetime.strptime(l[3], "%d/%m/%Y")
        if date > threshold:
            print(salary * 0.9)
```

Since you are parsing a csv file you might have a look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

Answer (score 0):

Such manipulations are much easier once you parse your data into a propper datastructure. Then do your manipulation there and write out the result.

Your data looks like [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/index.html) could help you here. And especially their [csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) parsing and writing. You would need to tell them about your delimiters and date structure, but once there you should have a table with numbers, strings dates etc.

Then you could query all the rows before a certain date and reduce the salary by 10%.